# customRecord not defined SuiteScript 2.0 UE

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

Attempting to write a script to pull data from a record into a new record type using an User Event Script. I continue to get an this error: ReferenceError: {custom record type} is not defined at object.afterSubmit.

This is the portion of the code that is failing. This first line is specifically being called out as not defining the custom record. I have it set to the custom record internal ID name.

// Set the value for the 'Name" field
customrecord_sample_record_wo_log.setValue({
fieldid: 'name',
Value: 'DEL-001'

Answer (score 0):

`customrecord_sample_record_wo_log` is the ***ID of the record type,*** not an instance of the record.  To create an instance of the record type you need to use the `record.create()` method.

```
var customRecord = record.create({
    type: 'customrecord_sample_record_wo_log'
});
```

Now you can reference the newly created record as `customRecord`:

```
customRecord.setValue({
    fieldId: 'name',
    value: 'DEL-001'
});
```

*Note that `record.create` assumes you have defined the `N/record` module as `record` at the top of your script:*

```
define(['N/record'], function (record) {...}
```